# Mysql workaround for window functions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an event table that has the following fields:

```
event_id
event_type 
event_time
```

Given a duration `D` and a number `k`, I need a count of all the `event_type`'s that had more than `K` events in any relative time window of duration `D`. This basically requires a sliding window with respect to each event. For example, I want all the event_type's that had activity of more than 5 events in any 10 minute duration.

I am not sure how to work around this without window functions.

(I am on mysql 5.6. I am talking about a dataset of under 1 million rows.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL has no window function support, but you can use a correlated subqueries in the `SELECT` list to retrieve exactly one column:

```
SELECT
  event_id,
  event_type, 
  event_time,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events EC WHERE EC.event_type = E.event_type AND EC.event_time > E.event_time) AS subsequent_event_count
FROM
  events E
WHERE ...
```

Do `EXPLAIN` it. This is kinda the same in terms of execution logic as the  `CROSS APPLY` in SQL Server.

Another approach is a self join:

```
SELECT
  E.event_id,
  E.event_type,
  E.event_time,
  COUNT(EC.event_id) AS subsequent_event_count
FROM
  events E
  LEFT JOIN events EC
    ON E.event_type = EC.event_type AND E.event_type < EC.event_type
GROUP BY
  E.event_id,
  E.event_type,
  E.event_time
```

Do test both approaches for performance.

You can do much more creative joins, like

```
EC.event_time > E.event_time AND EC.event_time < E.event_time + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: MySQL 8 has Window Functions now: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

Notice that this lack of functionality is a thing of the past with MySQL 8 and later:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Rearranged whole answer**

Now I understand what you expect.

I've created such a test table on my MySQL and this seems to work:

```
SELECT e2.event_type FROM events e1
JOIN events e2 
    ON e1.event_time BETWEEN e2.event_time AND (e2.event_time + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
GROUP BY e1.event_id, e2.event_type
HAVING count(e2.event_type) >= 5
```

Basically, for each event you self join events with specified relative time window (from `event_time` to `event_time` + window duration), and then you group by **e1**'s `even_id` to get emulated floating time window. Also we're gruping by `event_type` here because you want to get this field values for each window.

All you need to think through is performance. I'm not sure if it will be efficient enough for a 1M of records.

Comment: The time range is not static. It is relative each event. @dragoste

Comment: Well, you said *specified*. I thought specified is specified, not relative. ;-)

Comment: Agreed. I have updated my question with more clarifications. @dragoste

Comment: @smartnut007 I've updated my answer. I may help you.

Answer (score -1):

Do CTE's work fast enough?

```
WITH etypes_in_range AS (
SELECT tn.event_type,
       count(1) AS num
  FROM tablename tn
 WHERE tn.event_time < time_interval_end
   AND tn.event_time > time_interval_start
 GROUP BY tn.event_type
 HAVING count(1) > 5)
SELECT count(1)
  FROM etypes_in_range
```

Comment: MySQL does not support the with clause.

Comment: @LukasEder That is true, however MySQL 8 was nowhere in 2016 :) (You don't have to tag me just to say, that a newer version of a software has new features ;))