# PERCENT RANK does not work in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

Piece of MySQL code that works fine on my local MySQL server (8.0.12) does not work on Google Cloud SQL. How can I make it work on Cloud SQL?

Clearly the problem is related to OVER() which might not be allowed in MySQL 5.7 but is there a way around?

```
`SELECT id, impact, PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY impact) as percentile_rank
FROM applications;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

The reason here is that Google Cloud SQL is an implementation of either MySQL 5.6 or 5.7 depending on your choice. Window functions don't arrive in MySQL until 8, which is why they work on your local and not on Google.

As a work around you'll need to perform a correlated subquery. You can find out more on this answer: [Mysql workaround for window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538350/mysql-workaround-for-window-functions)

EDIT June 2021: Google Cloud SQL now offers MySQL 8, so your query will run, but you need to upgrade first.