# Group by 200 rows, start with newest ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I have table with columns `ID` and `amount`. Highest `ID` corresponds to newest record. I want to have summary by each 200 range of IDs, where the grouping starts with the newest record, e.g.:

```
ID     Amount
42153   1
...     1
41954   1
41953   2
...     2
41754   2
```

Would return:

```
last_id amount
42153   200 (= 100 x 1)
41953   400 (= 200 x 2)
```

This is for illustration only, I don't have such nice amounts in my data.

I am thinking this must be possible from having `ID` and max `ID`, which I can get easily:

```
select 
    id,
    (select max(id) from my_table) as mid
 from 
    my_table
```

I've tried some combinations with `mod()` or `truncate()` but nothing worked.

Sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dca02/2

My db version does not allow for window question.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and make the scale smaller like use 20 records in total and group on 2 records .. Then we have better example data and expected results to work with..

Comment: sample table data and output is helpful

Comment: @TomasGreif . . . I don't understand what you are trying to group.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added sample data and adjusted the question slightly. I am trying to group the ID column by range of 200. E.g. if max ID in the table is 410, I want to group rows with IDs 211 - 410, 11 - 210, 1 - 10.

Answer (score 2):

If your MySql version (8.0+ I think) supports windows functions, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    amount, 
    FLOOR(((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) -1) / 200)) AS grouping_val
  FROM my_table
) src
GROUP BY grouping_val
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cB4SEbL5AzJr75zkxaagA3/3)

**Update**
Updated to work without window function:

```sql
SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id, SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM (
  SELECT id, amount,
    FLOOR(
      (
        (
          (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM my_table t2 
            WHERE t2.id > t1.id -- Simulate ROW_NUMBER()
            ORDER BY t2.id
          ) 
        ) / 200
      )
    ) AS grouping_val
  FROM my_table t1
) src
GROUP BY grouping_val
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
;
```

[DB Fiddle (new)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cB4SEbL5AzJr75zkxaagA3/5)
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538350/mysql-workaround-for-window-functions)

I'm still not clear if you want to do ranges of 200 rows, or start with the highest ID value `x` and only capture rows with ranges of id's between `x AND (x - 200)`, `(x - 200) AND (x - 400)` and so on.  The SQL above handles the former.

Comment: *"If your MySql version (8.0+ I think) supports windows functions"* Only MySQL 8+ indeed supports windows functions

Comment: The outer query should use the plain old `GROUP BY` since OP seems to be interested in grouped data.