# mysql equivalent of over function in lower versions

Tags: mysql

I wrote the following query for a project of mine, it is working perfect, however it is working only for mysql 8 since I am using 'over' function in the query which is not supported by earlier mysql versions. I need to rewrite the query without using over so that it will work for lower versions of mysql as well.

```
$new_query   = "
update ospos_sales_items t
inner join (
    select sales_items_id, sum(total_amount) over(order by sales_items_id) sum_rate
    from ospos_sales_items t
    where payment_type = 'Credit' AND t.customer_id = $pid
     
) t1 on t1.sales_items_id = t.sales_items_id
set 
    t.payment_type = 'Cash',
    t.total_amount = case when t1.sum_rate >= $amount then t1.sum_rate - $amount else (t.total_amount) end,
    t.payment_type = case when t1.sum_rate >= $amount then 'Credit' else 'Cash' end
where t1.sum_rate - (t.total_amount) < $amount AND t.customer_id = $pid
";
```

I tried the below but it is not working.

```
$new_query   = "
update ospos_sales_items t
inner join (
    select sales_items_id, sum(total_amount)  sum_rate
    from ospos_sales_items t
    where payment_type = 'Credit' AND t.customer_id = $pid
     
) t1 on t1.sales_items_id = t.sales_items_id
set 
    t.payment_type = 'Cash',
    t.total_amount = case when t1.sum_rate >= $amount then t1.sum_rate - $amount else (t.total_amount) end,
    t.payment_type = case when t1.sum_rate >= $amount then 'Credit' else 'Cash' end
where t1.sum_rate - (t.total_amount) < $amount AND t.customer_id = $pid
";
```

UPDATE:

I have simplified the subquery that is using over so that an answer can be easy, please check the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce35508e9bb332dfe14b7ae92873fc62) suggest how to write the query without using over function but get the same results as the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce35508e9bb332dfe14b7ae92873fc62)

```
select  sum(total_amount)  over(order by item_id) sum_rate from mytable order by item_id
```

Comment: What does "over" do in your first example?

Comment: it is too complicated for me to explain what over actually do, I got this code written after a lot of tries and searching SO and asking.

Comment: Well, how are you expected to fix this code if you don't first understand it yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql workaround for window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538350/mysql-workaround-for-window-functions)

Comment: nope, please check my update and see if you can help.

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries- and whether it's worth sacrificing security for the sake of backwards compatibility

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(y.total_amount) sum_rate 
  from mytable x 
  join mytable y 
    on y.item_id <= x.item_id 
 group
    by x.item_id
 order
    by  x.item_id
```

Comment: the code works well when the db has minimal records, but it takes forever to complete with db having several records.  I tried testing by removing < in join but the result is different and not correct. Any way to improve the performance of your code?

Comment: Upgrade? You can do a solution with variables, but variables are (I think) deprecated in the latest version of MySQL

Comment: I solved it using variables as you suggested since an upgrade is not an option here.